# Update Mysql table data using array

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I have an Array that looks like the following when output through print_r();

```
$arr = Array
(
    [14] => Array
        (
            [url] => AllConsuming.net
            [da] => 48
            [pa] => 54.4
            [moz_rank] => 5.1
            [linksln] => 2123
            [equity] => 1318
            [alexa_rank] => 1725106
            [a_links] => 197
            [a_cnt] => GB
            [a_cnt_rank] => 123484
            [sem_rush_domain] => notfound
            [sr_rank] => 0
            [sr_kwords] => 0
            [sr_traffic] => 0
            [sr_costs] => 0
            [sr_ulinks] => 514
            [sr_hlinks] => 4154
            [sr_dlinks] => 12732
            [cf] => 34
            [tf] => 21
            [ebl] => 108777
            [ref_domains] => 1113
        )
[15] => Array
    (
        [url] => TravelIntelligence.net
        [da] => 31.7
        [pa] => 33.3
        [moz_rank] => 2.9
        [linksln] => 1
        [equity] => 1
        [alexa_rank] => 4265239
        [a_links] => 98
        [a_cnt] => N/A
        [a_cnt_rank] => N/A
        [sem_rush_domain] => notfound
        [sr_rank] => 0
        [sr_kwords] => 0
        [sr_traffic] => 0
        [sr_costs] => 0
        [sr_ulinks] => 1
        [sr_hlinks] => 3
        [sr_dlinks] => 3542
        [cf] => 22
        [tf] => 19
        [ebl] => 6368
        [ref_domains] => 531
    )
```

)

**The Mysql table looks like below:**

[Mysql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wa9F.png)

I would like to update this data into the MySQL table with each element value belonging to its respective field. Key of array i.e. 14, 15 are the primary key of the MySQL table.

I hope some genius can help me to solve out this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: what did you tried to do ?

Comment: Yes this can be done. You can use a foreach or some other iteration function to build the mysql query from this data.

Comment: Hello @hassan, I didn't get any idea how does it. I'm stuck. If you have any idea then please give me. Thank you..

Comment: are you using PDO?

Comment: Thank you  @Jerodev

Comment: Yes @Constantin GALBENU

Comment: @Pooja you put the question asking for solutions without even giving what you try? The world is not working like this

Comment: @developer, I tried out after I put for that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Pooja you can use below concept:

```
 <?php
$arr = array(
        "14" => array(
                "url" => "AllConsuming.net",
                "da" => 48,
                "pa" => 54.4,
                "moz_rank" => 5.1,
                "linksln" => 2123,
                "equity" => 1318,
                "alexa_rank" => 1725106,
                "a_links" => 197,
                "a_cnt" => "GB",
                "a_cnt_rank" => 123484,
                "sem_rush_domain" => "notfound",
                "sr_rank" => 0,
                "sr_kwords" => 0,
                "sr_traffic" => 0,
                "sr_costs" => 0,
                "sr_ulinks" => 514,
                "sr_hlinks" => 4154,
                "sr_dlinks" => 12732,
                "cf" => 34,
                "tf" => 21,
                "ebl" => 108777,
                "ref_domains" => 1113,
            ),
        "15" => array(
            "url" => "TravelIntelligence.net",
            "da" => 31.7,
            "pa" => 33.3,
            "moz_rank" => 2.9,
            "linksln" => 1,
            "equity" => 1,
            "alexa_rank" => 4265239,
            "a_links" => 98,
            "a_cnt" => "N/A",
            "a_cnt_rank" => "N/A",
            "sem_rush_domain" => "notfound",
            "sr_rank" => 0,
            "sr_kwords" => 0,
            "sr_traffic" => 0,
            "sr_costs" => 0,
            "sr_ulinks" => 1,
            "sr_hlinks" => 3,
            "sr_dlinks" => 3542,
            "cf" => 22,
            "tf" => 19,
            "ebl" => 6368,
            "ref_domains" => 531
        )
    );

$yourTableColumnArray = array("url", "cost", "categroy_1", "categroy_2", "categroy_3", "language", "f_n", "publishers", "da", "tf", "sr_traffic", "pa", "moz_rank", "linksln", "equity", "alexa_rank", "a_links", "a_cnt", "a_cnt_rank");

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $id = $key;
    $columnAndValue = array();
    foreach($value as $k => $val){
        if(in_array($val, $yourTableColumnArray)){
            $columnAndValue[$k] = $val;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($columnAndValue)){
        //your query like below:
        $query = "UPDATE yourTableName SET";
        foreach($columnAndValue as $ky => $vl){
            $query .= " ".$ky."=".$vl;
            end($columnAndValue);
            if(key($columnAndValue) != $ky){
              $query .= ",";
            }

        }
        $query .= " where out_id = $id"; 
        echo $query."<br>"; //just to know, the actual query formed for the current array(for 14 or 15)

        // now code here to execute your query with $query variable

    }
    $columnAndValue = array();
}
```

> Output

for the array key = 14 the query will be:

UPDATE yourTableName SET sr_rank=0, sr_kwords=0, sr_traffic=0, sr_costs=0 where out_id = 14

for the array key = 15 the query will be:

UPDATE yourTableName SET sr_rank=0, sr_kwords=0, sr_traffic=0, sr_costs=0 where out_id = 15

Comment: your query work on single record updations. Can you help me how to update multiple records. For ex. I have in the array there are two records, i.e. 14 and 15. So, at a time I have to update both records in the database. Please help me. Thank you...

Comment: @Pooja please check the updated one and tick mark it if it works for you..

Comment: @ Constantin GALBENU if this is so, then please edit my answer according to you where the code will be free of sql injection attack

Comment: Thank you vry much @BunkerBoy

Comment: @Pooja use prepared statement, it will secure from sql injections

Comment: @BunkerBoy, I have done it with a prepared statement.

Comment: so now i don't think so there is any risk in this code @ Constantin GALBENU  m i right ?

Comment: if she is using prepared statement like you answered below then would you please tell me now how that code is still prone to sql injection , if this is so then your answered is also prone to sql injection?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate `$arr` using a `foreach` to build a prepared statement, like this:

```
/** @var \PDO $dbHandle */

foreach ($arr as $id => $row) {

    $row['out_id'] = $id;

    $setInstructions = array_map(function ($key) {
        return "'$key' = :$key";
    }, array_keys($row));

    $columnNamesWithSemicolon = array_map(function ($key) {
        return ":$key";
    }, array_keys($row));

    $result = $dbHandle->prepare("UPDATE your_table SET " . implode(',', $setInstructions) . " WHERE out_id = :out_id");

    $result->execute(array_combine($columnNamesWithSemicolon, array_values($row)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Constantin GALBENU

Comment: Hello @Constantin GALBENU, Can you explain me your flow of to build query?

Comment: Your solution is correct but I have to update multiple records. For ex. I have in the array there are two record, i.e. 14 and 15. So, at a time I have to update both records in the MySQL table. Please help me. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
    $paramquery = array();
    $paramquery['primarykey'] = $key;  
    $paramquery['goes on your column name'] = $val_every_row['every key matched column'];
    ------ goes on your column and fill it with your column data  


    INSERT OR UPDATE HERE
    $this->model->whateverfunction($paramquery);

}
```

its pretty easy, its gonna be easier if you post data as json anyway. but this is the big picture for it